# Encrypting MonetDB Database

Tags: encryption, monetdb

I'm using a monetdb database to store massive amounts of sensor data such as data from accelerometers and gyroscopes. Now I need to restrict the access to the data. To restrict the access through the database interface (by use of SQL) I created a user account with password. The problem now is that I also want to prevent the access on the level of the file system (e.g. copy the data and load it to another monetdb installation).

Is there any way to tell monetDB to encrypt the files that are written to the filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Perhaps consider an encrypted file system?